# JS/jQuery - Better to run event handler in $(document).ready or in called function

Tags: javascript, jquery

*Note: The following question is not meant to be for people's opinion but is being asked in terms of best processing speed for the webpage, jQuery, etc.

I currently have code which follows the below "test" code format:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.my-class').on('click') {
    if ($('.my-class').hasClass('active') {
      $('.my-class').removeClass('active');
      return;
    }
    $('.my-class').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

My question is: should the event handler (not the event listener) be in the same code structure as `$(document).ready();`? Or should it look like this:

```
function toggler(obj) {    
  if ($(obj).hasClass('active') {
    $(obj).removeClass('active');
    return;
  }
  $(obj).addClass('active');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.my-class').on('click') {
    toggler(this);
  }
});
```

i.e. should `$(document).ready();` only have the listeners which reference the handlers or should the entire action (of listening and handling) be in `$(document).ready();`

**What is the proper way of doing this so as to maximize the usability/power of jQuery, JS, etc.**

Comment: [This](http://blog.calyptus.eu/seb/2011/01/javascript-call-performance-just-inline-it/) blog post says its faster without separate fuunction

Comment: I'd say that you should only declare a function when you think that you might use it a second time, also such micro-optimization should not be your concern considering you're using jQuery of all things. Although this has nothing to do with your question, your first and second code are different, one would remove then re-add class "active" on every '.my-class' elements, while the second one would act on the clicked one only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the first snippet of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.my-class').on('click') {
    if ($('.my-class').hasClass('active') {
      $('.my-class').removeClass('active');
      return;
    }
    $('.my-class').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

You are not doing anything with the `function toggler` before the DOM is ready, so why define it outside.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry about giving a general and obvious answer :
To be sure, only one way, doing benchmark. Using PHP for generating 100 elements, we could do :

```
<html><head>
...
</head><body>
<?php
    for ($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
        echo '<div class="my-class">Test</div>';
    }
?>
<script>
function toggler(obj) {    
  if ($(obj).hasClass('active') {
    $(obj).removeClass('active');
    return;
  }
  $(obj).addClass('active');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.my-class').on('click') {
    toggler(this);
  }
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

Create another php file with your other javascript implementation, then run them. Look how long the page/DOM takes to load, and how long it takes to manage the click event (using your browser toolkit).
Increase the number of genereted elements if you can't notice any difference between the two version.

Going this way will help you to solve every optimization problem you could meet ("honest" benchmark are somtimes tricky to make).